# C# cleaner view controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm currently refactoring some code I wrote when I was less experienced and have been moving logic from my controller to some models in an attempt to make my controller a bit more readable.

There's one function I'm not 100% sure on which will email a form from a view once it has been submitted. The problem code is written as:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> NewUser(Request model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            Offer_Request req1 = new Offer_Request();
            Offer_Request req2 = new Offer_Request();
            req1.Request = req2.Request= model;
            req1.offerID = 1;
            req2.offerID = 2;

            using (var ctx = new UserDBEntities())
            {
                ctx.Request.Add(model);
                ctx.Offer_Request.Add(req1);
                ctx.Offer_Request.Add(req2);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            string link1 = Url.Action("EmailHandler", "Home", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            string link2 = Url.Action("EmailHandler", "Home", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            link1 = link1 + "?id=" + req1.ID.ToString();
            link2 = link2 + "?id=" + req2.ID.ToString();
            var body = "<p>New request from {0} at {1}</p><p>Please choose from the following</p><br><p>One day access token:</p><p>{2}</p><br><p>5 day access token</p><p>{3}</p>";
            var subject = "{0} wants to connect!";
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(model.SponsorEmail));
            message.From = new MailAddress(##########);
            message.Subject = string.Format(subject, model.FirstName);
            message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FirstName, model.Email, link1, link2);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential("########", "##########");
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Sent");
        }
```

I'm wondering if I should move the email logic to a model, and if I can pass my Request model; to said model for processing. Also there is some database operations taking place which is fairly short and makes me wonder if it's worth leaving this in the controller of moving it also. What is the best code practice here? (Credentials removed for obvious reasons)

Comment: It should not be in your model. Either refactor the code into a private method in the controller, or better, create a separate service that is caller by the controller method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hey thanks for the response! I'm currently creating classes in the "models" folder which are called by my controller to run their various methods. I'm not entirely sure what it means to put these models into a separate service would that mean creating a new file within my solution (ie. moving classes from models into my solution directory)?

Comment: No, the models don't go in a separate service - the method to send the email does - a class that contains a method, say, `SendEmail(...)` (and that class would implement an interface so you can inject it into your controller using DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstracting out credentials is always going to be a more secure option when the application in published as they then get wrapped in a DLL. DLL's can be deconstructed and reverse engineered so it's not a fool-proof method to protect code but does help.

I tend to have three layers to my application for security and tidiness. First I have the DataAccess Layer in one project, the Business Logic in another and all the controller does is bring it all together in the one place. So it also seperates out the UI too. I've fouind this to be the standard practise for most UK software development companies. You can abstract out further if you wish to and places such as Insurance Companies and Financial Institutions can have 20 or 30 layers depending on how the data needs manipulating throughout, but for personal projects I find the three layers work fine.

Hope some of that rambling helps!

Comment: Hey that makes sense as far as design goes - however, when it comes to dataAccess and businessLogic I'm not sure what classifies as one or the other. 

Would a program using this format have a structure such that views and the view controller are in one project; database read and write, data models and the required config is in another; business logic (I assume) would consist of methods to compose and send emails, make API calls and manage responses. With the required information being sent between projects as required?

Comment: As a rule - Data Acess does nothing but manage data (so pull from a db server etc.), the business layer then manipulates it into place to fit with the way you need to delivered to your view - so all the credentials sotrage and processing would be on the data layer, if you needed to change it, put it a new class, add to it etc that would be done in the business layer - then your controller for your UI (views) will grab all that manipulated data and put it into you model in a user friendly way :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually what is kept inside a controller is just firing a `command` from an `interface` implementation let's say (SendEmail method) which makes the controller being not dependent on how the mail is sent.

This means that the controller is only responsible to connect view with model. So the logic should be ideally sit somewhere in model or a service.

Then that service is injected into controller by DI.